# Remote attribute in mymodule.libraries.yml

Tags: 8, theming

When creating a library, I noticed there is an attribute `remote` that can be added. I cannot really find any good documentation as to what it is for nor does it seem like it is required.

Questions:

1. What is the purpose of this `remote` when defining a library?
2. How can we be sure the value we add is correct?

Example from [https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme):

```
font-awesome:
  remote: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/
  version: 4.5.0
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/license/
    gpl-compatible: true
  css:
    theme:
      https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css: { type: external, minified: true }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code/comments in [`LibraryDiscoveryParser::buildByExtension`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Asset%21LibraryDiscoveryParser.php/function/LibraryDiscoveryParser%3A%3AbuildByExtension/8.7.x), it's to help ensure licensing info is included for 3rd party libraries:

```
// If this is a 3rd party library, the license info is required.
if (isset($library['remote']) && !isset($library['license'])) {
  throw new LibraryDefinitionMissingLicenseException(sprintf("Missing license information in library definition for definition '%s' extension '%s': it has a remote, but no license.", $id, $extension));
}
```

It's also mentioned in the [library docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module#external), but it just says that it's a good idea to include the remote info, not why. It doesn't appear to be used in the code other than the licensing, so I think it's safe to assume it's a reference/info value for now. There is no incorrect value to-to-speak, but it would make sense to set it to the URL of the project you're referencing.